# Powershell - User group membership from text file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a list of users and I want to export their group names, sorted A-Z.  The following script is not working in the inner `ForEach-Object` loop.

```
Get-Content users.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_; 

    Get-ADUser –Identity $user –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | sort

    ForEach-Object {

        New-Object PSObject -property @{User=$user;Group=$_;}

    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'your_file_path.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What is the goal of improvement?  Readability?  CPU Efficiency?  Memory Efficiency?  Speed?  Error handling?

Comment: I guess 'making it work', because the nested `foreach-object` has no input.

Comment: You need to clarify the question then so that readers will know what you need.

Comment: @Tony Hinkle  Sorry guys. My post was edited by super admin. I am a powershell noob!. I have a list of users, I want to sort per user groups memership by A-Z then export their group membership names only. This script exports the CH# Plus OU etc etc. How can I improve the script please ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Sorry

Answer (score 0):

The ForEach-Object is just sitting out there alone--you have to either pipe an object to it, or assign the object to a variable and use `foreach` to loop through the object instead.  I took the second approach below as excessive piping makes scripts difficult to read (for me).

```
Get-Content c:\temp\users.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_; 

    $AdUser = Get-ADUser –Identity $user –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | get-adgroup | select -ExpandProperty Name | sort

    foreach($group in $AdUser) {

        New-Object PSObject -property @{User=$user;Group=$group;} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\out.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append

    }
}
```

...and if you want to pipe it and use `ForEach-Object`, you just need to put a pipe after the `sort` and move the `Export-Csv`so that it exports the new object that was created:

```
Get-Content c:\temp\users.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_; 

    Get-ADUser –Identity $user –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | get-adgroup | select -ExpandProperty Name | sort | 

    ForEach-Object {
        New-Object PSObject -property @{User=$user;Group=$_;} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\out.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: hunkle - Many thanks for the reply. I have a list of users, I want to sort per user group memership names only by A-Z then export their group membership names only. This script exports the CH# Plus OU etc etc. How can I improve the script please ? Thanks

Comment: @kbriaz I have updated the answer so that the output includes the group names only, not to distinguished names.

Comment: Many thanks. Script works like magic, it exports all group names of the users in the list. However, I get following error within the PowerShell window.  (get-adgroup : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=\#XXX United Kingdom All(1),OU=XXX Groups,OU=XXX
Groups,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XX' under: 'DC=XX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX') Any idea why this ? Should I just ignore it ? As the export contains the data which I need. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for your help again. Ta

Comment: I have no idea why it would throw that error.  Passing the distinguished name is a valid input for get-adgroup (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)